# Joint Probability Distribution with Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Given that continuous random variables X and Y have the following joint probability distribution function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{2}{3}$$

for $x^2\le y \le 1 $ and $0 \le x \lt 1 $

(a) What is the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X = x$ (that is, $h(y|x))$?
(b) Compute for $h(y|\frac{1}{4})$. Over what range of $y$ is this defined?

Attempting to solve for (a)

$$f(x) = \int_{x^2}^1 \frac{2}{3} dy $$
$$=\frac{2}{3}y|_{x^2}^1$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}(1-x^2), x^2 \le 1$$

$$f(y) = \int_{0}^1 \frac{2}{3} dx $$
$$=\frac{2}{3}x|_{0}^1$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}, 0 \le x \lt 1$$

$$f(y|x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}$$
$$= \frac{1}{(1-x^2)}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? Posting your attempt to solve the problem will help us help you! :)

Comment: The easiest way to solve this problem is to draw a sketch of the $x$-$y$ plane and indicate on it the region on which $f(x,y)$ has value $\frac 23$.

Comment: I am confused with the $x^2 \le y \le 1$ thing. How do i go about it?

Comment: @SplitInfinity i attempted to solve the conditional probability, am i doing it right?

Comment: Actually, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, $$f(y\mid x)=\frac{\mathbf 1_{x^2<y<1}}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: so that means, $$f(y|x) = \frac{1}{(1-x^2)} ; x^2 \lt y \lt 1$$

Comment: are my computations correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computations for $f_X(x)$ and $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$ are okay.

$$\begin{align}f_X(x) & = \int_{x^2}^1 \tfrac 23\mathop{\rm d}y\cdot \mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1} \\[1ex] & = \tfrac 23(1-x^2)\cdot \mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1}\\[2ex] f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) & = (1-x^2)^{-1}\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq x^2\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq x\leq 1}\end{align}$$

Your evaluation of $f_Y(y)$ has gone astray.

Since $\big\{(x,y):x^2\leq y\leq 1~,~ 0\leq x\leq 1\big\}$ is $\big\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq \sqrt y~,~ 0\leq y\leq 1\big\}$, therefore:

$$\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= \int_0^{\surd y} \tfrac 23 \mathop{\rm d}x\cdot \mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}\\[1ex] &\ddots \end{align}$$

Comment: haha, I like your comment "gone astray". Thanks, I realized that $f(y)$ is not necessary.